# Calculate error, MSE and MAPE?

Tags: r

I created this program to estimate the Mean Squared Error (MSE), and Mean absolute percent error (MAPE):
Is everything all right with this?
`pune` is an .csv file with 22 data points.

```
pune <- read.csv("C:/Users/ervis/Desktop/Te dhenat e konsum energji/pune.csv", header=T,dec=",", sep=";")
pune <- data.matrix(pune,rownames.force=NA)
m1 <- seq(from = 14274.19, to = 14458.17, length.out = 10000)
MSE1 <- numeric(length = 10000)
for(i in seq_along(MSE1)) {
 MSE1[i] <- 1 / length(pune) * sum((pune-m1[i]) ^ 2)
}
MAPE1 <- numeric(length = 10000)
for(i in seq_along(MAPE1)) {
 MAPE1[i] <- 1 / length(pune) * sum(abs((pune-m1[i]) / pune))
}
```

Am I right?

Comment: Please do not copy-paste your workspace, but try to provide real code. Also come with a specific problem, just asking whether your calculation is OK is not what this site is for.

Comment: @user687286: When you are writing questions, try to remove any lines of code that aren't relevant.  For example, we don't need to know what you called your data file (just give us the data), or the about the error you accidently threw, or about any other calculations that weren't directly related to calculating the MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a lot of code for a simple calculation. Here is how I would do it for a data vector `a`:

```
a = c(1:10)
mse_a = sum((a - mean(a)) ^ 2) / length(a)
```

From what I can see your formula for MSE is correct, but there should only be one value for the whole dataset, not multiple values.

If your data only contains 22 points, I can't see why you need to create a 10,000 item vector, regardless of whether you are using loops or not.

Comment: i am using an interval from 14274.19 to 14458.17, and i want to know which is the best from this interval, the one who gives me min(MSE)

Comment: I don't follow. You are looking for the mean which gives you the minimum MSE? If so, that does not make sense because the mean is dependent on the data used to calculate MSE, you can't pick an arbitrary mean. The only value it will be valid for is when it is equal to the real mean of your data points.

Comment: sorry maybe I was not clear.
I have 22 data, and assume that I have 10,000 approximate values, of which i will choose the one who gives me the minimum of MSE

Comment: Suppose that instead of "mean(a)" to want to put one by one the values ​​of my interval

Comment: I don't think that works, statistically, because the mean is a property of your data points. If you change the mean without changing the data points, then MSE you obtain is not valid.

Comment: I first calculated bootstrap confidence interval, but i am worried about the high values ​​derived from the calculation of MSE

Answer (score 9):

[Mean squared error](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mean_squared_error) seems to have different meanings in different contexts.

For a random sample taken from a population, the MSE of the sample mean is just the variance divided by the number of samples, i.e.,

```
mse <- function(sample_mean) var(sample_mean) / length(sample_mean)
mse(pune)
```

For regressions, MSE means the sum of squares of residuals divided by the degreees of freedom of those residuals.

```
mse.lm <- function(lm_model) sum(residuals(lm_model) ^ 2) / lm_model$df.residual
#or
mse.lm <- function(lm_model) summary(lm_model)$sigma ^ 2
```